Could not be able to access external endpoint inside docker
I have docker container running in localhost. And inside this container I have created one python script to access one endpoint which is from another server. After executing docker-compose exec server bash command, I will be inside the container. I could not access this endpoint inside the container. When I try curl command to check, it returns connection timed out error.
For the same endpoint, if I try it anywhere outside container, it works.
The Python script is as follows
import requests

url = 'http://172.17.0.37:10352/api/samples'  # Replace with your endpoint
try:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=('admin@localhost','password'), verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an HTTPError for bad responses
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

And the docker-compose.yml file will be like this
version: "3.2"
services:
  server:
    image: image1
    build: ./docker/
    environment:
      L_PASSWORD: "password"
      L_LICENSE_FILE: "/opt/l/project/conf/esp.license"
    ports:
      - published: 8002
        target: 8002
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - published: 8003
        target: 1487
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /opt/l/project
      - type: volume
        source: data
        target: /opt/l/data
      - type: volume
        source: static
        target: /opt/l/server/lib/www/static
volumes:
  data: {}
  static: {}

Is this anything needs to be done so that I can access the external endpoint inside the docker container?
Has anyone gone through the similar issues and resolved? Kindly guide me.

Where does that IP address come from?  It vaguely looks like the same IP range a container might use (172.17.0.0/16 is often the default Docker network), is there potential IP conflict with Docker?

I don't think it conflicts with the IP address that I am using. Actually that IP address is some other application's which is running in vm
